# How can I save images to a folder using their string ids from Frontend?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating images dynamically with Jquery in Frontend. Then I'm moving these pictures' to the backend through a textbox and I am splitting according to the ',' character. Now I have an array of string ids. I am trying to save images to a folder using these ids. But I have no idea how to use these ids.

Like this, I need to use these ids:

```
string[] image_ids_st = txbx_image_ids.Text.Split(','); //["img1","img2"]
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

From the given information it is actually not quite clear what your goal is.

I understand you want to save the images + ids somewhere, I guess on the server where the back-end is hosted? 
This means you are making a REST call to the back-end which uses the ApiController in the System.Web.Http namespace, right? If you want to send the images to the back-end you can use Multipart Form Data or a JSON body containing the information Id and the byte stream of the image. For saving images in the back-end, you should read through this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: No, I won't save the ids. Ids already exist as string. But I'm trying to save these images from backend with these ids. I think I'm going to have to use ajax to get images then I will save to a folder.

Comment: Then send the image as byte[] in the HTTP Body. The endpoint must read the bytes and save them to the file storage.